# Как добавить картинку к элементу <li>

Tags: c#, html, html5, bootstrap, razor

Всем привет. Как я могу добавить картинку (glyphicon glyphicon-cog) к элементу "li" ?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li>@Html.ActionLink(SessionHelper.User.FullName, "Index", "Settings")</li>
  </ul>
```

Я пробовал вот так:

```
<li class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">@Html.ActionLink(SessionHelper.User.FullName, "Index", "Settings")</li>
```

Но почему то они появляются в разных местах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта:

- Добавление картинки перед ссылкой

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
      <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Settings")">@SessionHelper.User.FullName</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

- Картинка как часть ссылки

```html
<li>
  <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Settings")"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    @SessionHelper.User.FullName
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Второй вариант идеален в моем случае. Спасибо.